# Автоматический перевод текста на английский язык из Visual Basic

Tags: visual-basic

Есть программа QTranslate. Нужно создать приложение на Visual Basic, которая открывает
файл doc, сохраняет его как текст, передает QTranslate, переводит и сохраняет переведенный 
файл.Вероятно, нужно использовать функции API по имитации нажатия клавиш и перемещения мыши? Какие?

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такую версию:

Судя по описанию [QTranslate](http://quest-app.appspot.com/), эта программа использует один из веб-сервисов для перевода. Поэтому, Вашей программе всё-равно потребуется доступ в интернет.

**Шаг 1.** Выберите веб-сервис перевода, который вам нравится больше всего. Я предложил бы [Яндекс.Перевод](http://translate.yandex.ru/), так как там [документация на русском](http://api.yandex.ru/translate/). Проще будет разобраться.

**Шаг 2.** Изучите, как в Вашем языке программирования проще всего сделать веб-запрос. Я с дотнетом "на Вы", поэтому всё что нашел - это простейший класс [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb).

С его помощью Вы можете послать GET-запрос серверу Яндекс.Перевод, например, методом [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx)

**Шаг 3.** Ответ от сервера приходит либо в [XML](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)-, либо в [JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)-формате. Разберите ответ от сервера JSON- или XML-парсером. Навсидку я нашел в MSDN такой класс: [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx). Для Вашей задачи должно хватить.

[JSON-парасер](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json(v=vs.95).aspx) в .Net тоже есть, смотрите сами, что Вам больше понравится.

**Шаг 4.** Соедините всё воедино. Возьмите строку, которую нужно перевести. Оберните её в URL для запроса на сервер. Пошлите запрос и получите ответ. С помощью парсера получите из ответа строку перевода.

**PS**. И, да,

> имитация нажатия клавиш и перемещения
> мыши

не превращайтесь в быдлокодера.